# Hangfire Jobs not firing - no errors

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have only one hangfire server.  The job was working fine and works fine when it's manually fired.  It just doesn't fire at the time set.  It's a daily job set to fire at 7am.  When that didn't work i set the cron to 7:10.  Still won't fire.  Checked all logs and there is no error.  Dashboard shows as :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKWkW.png)

Which shows it should have fired an hour ago.  Config file for this job is :

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(t => t.Execute(), onceADayAt7AM, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

private const string onceADayAt7AM = "0 7 * * *";

Any ideas out there?

Hangfire 1.6.22,  .NET Core 2.2

Here is the Data entry from Hanfire.State Table :
{"StartedAt":"2021-04-20T13:32:04.8428793Z"

But the CRON says 7.  Not sure why it would be firing 6 hours and 32 minutes later?

Comment: Do you have access to the HangFire database? Do you see an entry is added in the `HangFire.State` table at the time the job is scheduled to be executed?

Comment: @DeMaki -  I do have acccess and added the row information to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: I am on HangFire 1.7.4 so not sure if the `HangFire.State` table is the same, but do you see 3 entries being created? First entry with Name "Enqueued" and Reason "Triggered by recurring job scheduler", followed by a 2nd entry with Name "Processing" and finally an entry with Name "Succeeded" or "Failed"? If so, is the "CreatedAt" timestamp for the "Enqueued" entry correct - or is this already not aligned with your cron?